# Access VBA with Outlook - ".To" Line displays Primary Key instead of Email information

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to display an outlook message based on information in my Form.

The ".To" line shows "Me.Email" which references a Combo Box in the Form.

I am trying to add E-mail addresses 
that are entered into a separate "Company" Table. The combo box displays e-mails, but the Outlook message the "To" line contains the Primary Key. How do I make it reference the e-mail rather than the Primary Key?

```
Private Sub Distribute_Click()

Dim oApp            As Object
Dim objOutlookMsg   As Object

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application") 'Set Outlook application

Set objOutlookMsg = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

With objOutlookMsg
    .To = Me.Email 'Only pulls the Primary Key ID number instead of e-mails?
    .Subject = Me.Name & " - Approval Letter"
    .Body = "Generic Message"
    .Display
End With

Set oMail = Nothing
Set oApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need the Primary Key in that combobox, remove the column from its source query, and adapt the combobox properties accordingly (number of columns, bound column, ...)

Or set the bound column to the column with the Email address.

Or use

```
.To = Me.Email.Columns(1)  ' guessing that Columns(0) is the ID
```

Comment: Yes! That's almost what I was looking for! But now I'm getting an error.

    .To = Me.Email.Column(1)

Column(0) is the ID and Column(1) is the company name, which works in the Outlook Message. 

But when I select Column(2) (email addresses) I'm getting Run-time error '-2147352571 (80020005)': Type Mismatch?

Comment: Check the value of .Column(2) with simple Debug.Print or set a break point on the line and hover your mouse over top of the variable to see what it actually is.